# How to use gridgain with two nodes where each node on its own different host

Tags: java, gridgain

Can anyone help me in guiding to use grid gain, The documentation on website is not enough and confusing. We have to run thousands of simulations in the LAN. can anyone help me in running compute grid on multiple hosts in a LAN. I am able to run compute example on multiple nodes on same host, but not on multiple nodes on multiple hosts. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compute examples are configured to work with local host settings. All you have to do is update IP addresses in `examples/config/example-compute.xml` file to the IP addresses in your environment. You only need to provide at least 1 IP address of the node you plan to start first, but you can provide more just in case.

Here are the configuration changes you have to make:

```
<bean id="grid.cfg" class="org.gridgain.grid.GridConfiguration">
    <!-- Remove this configuration property. -->
    <!--<property name="localHost" value="127.0.0.1"/>-->

    ...

    <!-- Explicitly configure TCP discovery SPI to provide list of initial nodes. -->
    <property name="discoverySpi">
        <bean class="org.gridgain.grid.spi.discovery.tcp.GridTcpDiscoverySpi">
            <property name="ipFinder">
                <!-- Uncomment multicast IP finder to enable multicast-based discovery of initial nodes. -->
    <bean class="org.gridgain.grid.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.GridTcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder">
                    <property name="addresses">
                        <list>
                            <!-- In distributed environment, replace with actual host IP address. -->
                            <value>127.0.0.1:47500..47509</value>
                        </list>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: using configuration: config/default-config.xml works. node in localhost and node in remote host are able to discover each other. I applied your mentioned changes in example-compute.xml for both local host and remote host, but these two node are still UNABLE to discover each other. I am using gridgain 6.1.8. Kindly help..Thanks

Comment: Config on My own localhost with Ip 10.244.10.95: http://pastebin.com/nyzL2aK0. Also Config on remote host with Ip 10.244.10.88: http://pastebin.com/03N2SnPN. Still they are unable to discover each other.Kindly help. Thanks –  Tapas 3 mins ago

Comment: Ok, please remove "localhost" parameter from both files, local and remote. Also, in the local and remote configs set IP in the discover SPI to "10.244.10.95". With this configuration, you need to start remote host first.

Comment: It worked... Thanks a lot... How can I set your above comment as correct answer.