# GridGain cluster on AWS using TcpDiscoverySpi in VPC, not clustering

Tags: amazon-ec2, tcp, gridgain, vpc

GridGain using yardstick on using TcpDiscoverySpi on aws ec2 instances launched into a VPC cant form a cluster.  what setting should i be looking at ?  thanks

my xml config

`<property name="discoverySpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                <property name="ipFinder">
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
                        <property name="addresses">
                            <list>
                                <value>10.0.0.245</value><value>10.0.0.246</value><value>10.0.0.247</value><value>10.0.0.35</value>
                            </list>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>`

some important log lines

ver. 1.0.0#20150329-sha1:5fc2cd05

INFO: OS user: ec2-user

INFO: IGNITE_HOME=/home/ec2-user/yardstick-ignite

INFO: Non-loopback local IPs: 10.0.0.245

INFO: Enabled local MACs: 0A5AEFFFF957

INFO: Successfully bound to TCP port [port=47100, locHost=/127.0.0.1]

INFO: Successfully bound to TCP port [port=47500, localHost=/127.0.0.1]

WARNING: Failed to connect to any address from IP finder (make sure IP finder addresses are correct and firewalls are disabled on all host machines): [/10.0.0.246:47500, /10.0.0.245:47500, /10.0.0.247:475
00, /10.0.0.35:47500]
Jul 13, 2015 7:41:09 PM org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger warning
WARNING: Failed to connect to any address from IP finder (make sure IP finder addresses are correct and firewalls are disabled on all host machines): [/10.0.0.247:47500, /10.0.0.245:47500, /10.0.0.35:4750
0, /10.0.0.246:47500]

I am running in an aws VPC using the default security group

where i have opened ports 47000 - 48500  for TCP

Answer (score 1):

my default security group was not configured correctly

and

I also did this

Remove this configuration property.

```
 <property name="localHost" value="127.0.0.1"/>
```

as this answer says

[How to use gridgain with two nodes where each node on its own different host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26800090/how-to-use-gridgain-with-two-nodes-where-each-node-on-its-own-different-host)